# How to obtain Census Tract Centroids when Bureau's web site unavailable?

Tags: centroids

Does anyone have the Census Bureau file of census tract centroid, for either 2000 or 2010 tracts? With the Bureau's web site shut down, the only available file is the EPA's, and it omits about 500 tracts.

Comment: Do you have the polygons - could just extract the centroids (sorry if that's a bit obvious!)?

Answer (score 1):

Esri has a **[census tract boundary dataset](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ca1316dba1b442d99cb76bc2436b9fdb)**.  Finding the centroid from there is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the National Historic GIS website hosted by the University of Minnesota at nhgis.org.  They have tract polygonsfor both Censuses you seek, which you could turn into centroids.The site does require you register before downloading though (it's free)